# Android Gallery Widget onScrollStateChanged

Tags: android, user-interface, widget, gallery

How can i set the `onScrollStateChanged` method for the Android Gallery Widget?

I would like to do something if the scrolling is finished.

Comment: Also need help with this.  Want to override the onItemClicked method of Gallery depending on whether the gallery is scrolling or not.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find exactly what you are looking for, but I would try using `Gallery`'s [onScroll](http://tinyurl.com/android-onscroll) method:

```
public boolean onScroll 
  (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
```

The last `onScroll` call, `e2.getAction(`) should be equal to `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Comment: Scroll states and motion events are two different things. I think the gallery widget should implement the interface onScrollStateChanged or i have to do so but i don't know how to connect the interface implementation to the view.

Comment: @Android-Dev: yep, but AFAIK it doesn't :(